# How to map gson value if array inside an array

Tags: android, json, gson

I m mapping **gson** response in android, getting a response from the server in gson, i found an array having the name "0", how can I map this as it is integer type so am I doing wrong something here. Please have a look here.

```html
{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "department list filter by hospital",
  "data": {
    "departments": [
      {
        "pk": "17",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "cardiology",
        "department_en": "Cardiology",
        "department_ar": "أمراض القلب",
        "desc_en": "<p><span xss=removed>Cardiology<\/span><br><\/p>",
        "desc_ar": "<p xss=removed>أمراض القلب<br><\/p>",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": [],
        "sub_departments_count": 0
      },
      {
        "pk": "19",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "elderly-services",
        "department_en": "Elderly services",
        "department_ar": "عربي",
        "desc_en": "",
        "desc_ar": "",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": [],
        "sub_departments_count": 0
      },
      {
        "pk": "16",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "neurology",
        "department_en": "Neurology",
        "department_ar": "قسم الأعصاب",
        "desc_en": "<p><span xss=removed>Neurology.<\/span><br><\/p>",
        "desc_ar": "<p xss=removed>قسم الأعصاب<br><\/p>",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": {
          "2": [
            {
              "pk": "6",
              "fk_hospital": "4",
              "fk_department": "16",
              "sub_department_slug": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_department_en": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_department_ar": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_desc_en": "<p>arrhythmias<br><\/p>",
              "sub_desc_ar": "<p>arrhythmias<br><\/p>",
              "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
              "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
              "department_en": "Neurology",
              "department_ar": "قسم الأعصاب"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sub_departments_count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": false
}{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "department list filter by hospital",
  "data": {
    "departments": [
      {
        "pk": "17",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "cardiology",
        "department_en": "Cardiology",
        "department_ar": "أمراض القلب",
        "desc_en": "<p><span xss=removed>Cardiology<\/span><br><\/p>",
        "desc_ar": "<p xss=removed>أمراض القلب<br><\/p>",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": [],
        "sub_departments_count": 0
      },
      {
        "pk": "19",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "elderly-services",
        "department_en": "Elderly services",
        "department_ar": "عربي",
        "desc_en": "",
        "desc_ar": "",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": [],
        "sub_departments_count": 0
      },
      {
        "pk": "16",
        "fk_hospital": "4",
        "department_slug": "neurology",
        "department_en": "Neurology",
        "department_ar": "قسم الأعصاب",
        "desc_en": "<p><span xss=removed>Neurology.<\/span><br><\/p>",
        "desc_ar": "<p xss=removed>قسم الأعصاب<br><\/p>",
        "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
        "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
        "hospital_slug": "adan-hospital",
        "sub_departments": {
          "2": [
            {
              "pk": "6",
              "fk_hospital": "4",
              "fk_department": "16",
              "sub_department_slug": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_department_en": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_department_ar": "arrhythmias",
              "sub_desc_en": "<p>arrhythmias<br><\/p>",
              "sub_desc_ar": "<p>arrhythmias<br><\/p>",
              "hospital_en": "Adan Hospital",
              "hospital_ar": "سدسد",
              "department_en": "Neurology",
              "department_ar": "قسم الأعصاب"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sub_departments_count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": false
}
```

Here are my Mapping Classes.

```
public class DepartmentsData {
public String result;
public String message;
public DepatmentData data;
public boolean errors ;}
```

second class

```
public class DepatmentData {
public List<DepartmentsItems> departments;}
```

third class

```
public class DepartmentsItems {
public int pk;
public int fk_hospital;
public String department_slug;
public String department_en;
public String department_ar;
public String desc_en;
public String desc_ar;
public String hospital_en;
public String hospital_ar;
public String hospital_slug;
public int sub_departments_count;
public List<SubDepartments> sub_departments;}
```

here is confused fourth class

```
public class SubDepartments {
public int pk;
public int fk_hospital;
public int fk_department;
public String sub_department_slug;
public String sub_department_en;
public String sub_department_ar;
public String sub_desc_en;
public String sub_desc_ar;
public String hospital_en;
public String hospital_ar;
public String department_en;
public String department_ar;}
```

in Gson there is another array inside **SubDepartments** array.but its name is 0 so I am confused here. Kindly suggest me anyother mapping best idea if its lengthy.

Comment: It doesn't have a 0... That's the size

Comment: @cricket_007 have I mapped it right? because its array inside an array.so should i use public List<List<SubDepartments>> sub_departments;  instead of public List<SubDepartments> sub_departments;?

Comment: @cricket_007 i have post it again please have a look its gson response 2 is not size but name of array

Comment: You've messed up the object, then, and can't use Gson because the JSON is not consistent. `"sub_departments": []` is an array, the other one is an object, which cannot be assigned to `List<SubDepartments>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have both

```
"sub_departments": {
      "2": [
```

And

```
"sub_departments": [],
```

It can only be an Object to be parsed successfully by default using Gson. You can try using some custom deserializer to detect and convert a JSON object into an array, if that is what you need. I'm not sure I can give an example of that, but the Gson documentation has a section on custom deserializers.

However, your data seems incorrect since `2` doesn't seem to map to anything, and it isn't the "index" of any of the other departments